# Best Practice for Running ROS Remotely

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am wondering what is the best practice to run ROS remotely.

I have read through http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleRemoteMachines, which goes through how to setup port forwarding on my local network and access the machine through the public IP address. I have not spent too much time to implement it, not sure why after using netcat -l 1234, the port 1234 is still not open from port checker website.

I am wondering if this is still best practice? Or should I use something like http://www.remote.it, and remote ssh/vnc into the robot. What would be the difference between the two in terms of performance, security and such.

Sincerely,
Sean

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380112/best-practice-for-running-ros-remotely/) by [sean112](https://answers.ros.org/users/50411/sean112/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without dismissing the effort the author of [wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleRemoteMachines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleRemoteMachines) put into that tutorial, I don't believe what is described there was ever a best practice (note: it's also not that old: first edits from end of 2018).

The tutorial essentially instructs users to setup port forwarding, which exposes ROS nodes directly on the public internet. **This is not a good idea**.

[STEP 2: Modem/Router Settings](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleRemoteMachines#STEP_2:_Modem.2FRouter_Settings) even suggests to forward *all TCP and UDP ports* between `1025` and `65000`. Exposing just about *all* ports of a machine to the public internet.

**This is also not a good idea**.

It's also unnecessary.

I would strongly recommend to use a VPN or some other form of tunnel between remote networks. This has many benefits, but two main ones:

1. all traffic will be encrypted (in contrast to plain `TCPROS` and `UDPROS` traffic, which is plain text)
2. only a single port (or a couple at most) needs to be exposed in a firewall

Whether you use a commercial service or something like [tinc-vpn](https://www.tinc-vpn.org) (OSS, peer-to-peer VPN) doesn't really matter.

As to performance: anything which needs to be encrypted and decrypted will incur overhead. But that's a non-issue here I believe, as transmitting ROS messages plain text over the public internet is basically an invitation for some rogue entity to take control of your robot(s), and additionally the types of encryption employed by VPN services are typically rather lightweight.

Without getting overly dramatic: only use port-forwarding if you absolutely cannot use something else.

---

Edit: I've added a strong warning to that tutorial to dissuade people from trying to implement it ([diff](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleRemoteMachines?action=diff&rev2=82&rev1=81)):

[image: warning]

I'm actually going to discuss with some other people whether that page should be removed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-12**:
Post on ROS Discourse: [Should we delete ROS/Tutorials/MultipleRemoteMachines?](https://discourse.ros.org/t/should-we-delete-ros-tutorials-multipleremotemachines/20898).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-14**:
We've decided to remove the page (actually: remove the content, but keep the page itself).

**Comment by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on 2021-06-14**:
@sean112 If you go for the vpn option take a look into this [repository](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn), it makes it really easy to setup a vpn server. I am using it in a project I am working on. Basically I set up the vpn server in my laptop and I connect the robot as a client to it. With this I am able to access the robot via internet.

**Comment by [sean112](https://answers.ros.org/users/50411/sean112/) on 2021-06-14**:
I have decided to use remote.it for remote ssh/vnc, it seems to be more secure and less work on our end.

**Comment by [sean112](https://answers.ros.org/users/50411/sean112/) on 2021-06-14**:
@rezenders Thanks for the suggestion, I will check it out definitely